# Load Error - Java

Tags: java, android

I used that to limit the editText numbers:

```
n1.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new DigitsKeyListener(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE) {
        int beforeDecimal = 3, afterDecimal = 1;

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            String temp = n1.getText() + source.toString();

            if (temp.equals(".")) {
                return "0.";
            }
            else if (temp.toString().indexOf(".") == -1) {
                // no decimal point placed yet
                if (temp.length() > beforeDecimal) {
                    return "";
                }
            } else {
                temp = temp.substring(temp.indexOf(".") + 1);
                if (temp.length() > afterDecimal) {
                    return "";
                }
            }

            return super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
        }
    }
});
```

And that to load the saved number:

```
public void car(View v)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder car = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    car.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    car.setTitle("Carregar");
    car.setMessage(R.string.car);
    car.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notas e pesos carregados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                prefs = getSharedPreferences("Notas_Salvas", MODE_PRIVATE);

                nota1.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA1","."));
                nota2.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA2",""));
                nota3.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA3",""));
                nota4.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA4","."));
                nota5.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA5",""));
                peso1.setText(prefs.getString("PESO1",""));
                peso2.setText(prefs.getString("PESO2",""));
                peso3.setText(prefs.getString("PESO3",""));
                peso4.setText(prefs.getString("PESO4",""));
                peso5.setText(prefs.getString("PESO5",""));
            }
        });
    car.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notas carregadas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            prefs = getSharedPreferences("Notas_Salvas", MODE_PRIVATE);

            nota1.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA1",""));
            nota2.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA2",""));
            nota3.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA3",""));
            nota4.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA4",""));
            nota5.setText(prefs.getString("NOTA5",""));
        }
    });
    car.show();
}
```

But when will load the saved number the editText doesn't load with the first click, he just delete the number existing. Then with the second click he load the numbers.

How to solve this?

Comment: show the button click code.